# c++ two dimensional array definition

Tags: c++

What is wrong in below

```
int data[2][2] = { {1,1}, {2,2}};
int sum = sum(data, 2);
```

Sum is defined as

```
int sum(int **data, int rows);
```

data contains the address of the `data[0]`, so it can be treated as a pointer. The `*data` leads me to the value, which is another array of type `int`. This another array should be treated as pointer to first element. Hence why do compiler complains at the argument for int `**data`?

I get a compiler error as show below. I understand the error, but my question is why `**data` is not acceptable.

```
error: cannot convert int (*)[2] to int** for argument 1 to int sum(int**, int)
```

Comment: What's the actual problem? Is it not compiling? If not, post the compiler output.

Comment: This question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165627/how-to-assign-two-dimensional-array-to-pointer

Answer (score 3):

No matter if an array is one-dimensional or multi-dimensional, it can only be converted to pointer to the first element, and *not* to pointer to array of pointers.

To understand why, analyze how arrays are laid out in memory.

```
int data[3]
0.......4.......8...... (assume sizeof(int)==4)
data[0] data[1] data[2]
^ &data[0]

int data[3][2]
0..........4..........8..........12.........16.........20........
data[0][0] data[0][1] data[1][0] data[1][1] data[2][0] data[2][1]
^ &data[0][0]
```

All elements are always laid out linearly, so every array (one or multi-dimensional) is representable as pointer to the first element (`arr[0][0]...[0]`), and only so. Multidimensional arrays can not be represented as pointer to array of pointers, because those arrays of pointers do not exist anywhere.

Dimensions are merely compile-time hints for translating into address (`arr[i][j]` becomes `*(array_memory + i*H + j)`). Pointer to pointer is entirely different structure than arrays; indexing it looks the same syntactically, but it causes entirely different thing to happen (`ppi[i][j]` becomes `*(*(ppi + i) + j)`.

Comment: Which spec states that a multi-dimensional array would be linear in ram?

Comment: @Jimm I can not find that in the standards, but the requirement for an  n-dimensional array to be implicitly convertible to pointer to (n-1)-dimensional array makes it the only possible option.

Answer (score 2):

You are supposed to include the size of the array in the definition of the parameters.

```
    int sum(int data[2][2], int rows);
```

Note: If it was a dynamic array, then what you did before is right.

Comment: Not entirely true, the way his function is declared is perfectly valid as well.

Comment: It seems Jimm wants to keep one dimension dynamic, so I guess `int sum(int data[][2], int rows);` is needed.

Comment: no, give the Dims in the call is a bad practice. and no what he did before was not right. not for what he meant it to be.

Answer (score 1):

May be this helps:

```
int sum(int *i, int rows) {
    cout << *i << *(i+1) << *(i+2) << *(i+3);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int data[2][2] = { {1,1}, {2,2}};
    int sum1 = sum(data[0], 2);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`int ** data` is a pointer to a pointer to an `int`.

Passing data to sums first argument is actually just passing a `int*` to it, which is not identical to `int **`.

Further, once you're in `sum()`, it has no idea that `int **data` points to a 2 dimensional array, it just knows it's a pointer to a pointer to an `int`...

Dereferencing data the first time gives you a pointer to an `int`.
Dereferencing data the second time gives you the `int`.

You'll need to change the interface to the `sum()` function.

Answer (score 0):

int data[2][2] // It's basically array of 4 values. it's not array of arrays.
the dimentionals just explain the compiler how to access a value.

lets say you have:

```
data[R][C]  
data[X][Y] == *(&data)[X*C + Y]
```

following this explanation, you should define you function:

```
int sum(int *data, int rows);
```

And if you want to show what it does, I may help you use it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The array-name-to-pointer decay only happens once, so you get a pointer, not a pointer-to-a-pointer.

A C/C++ array is a contiguous allocation of data elements.  An array of arrays is still a contiguous allocation of elements -- it's just that the elements are larger.  This is what your error message "`cannot convert int (*)[2] to int**`" is saying.

Another way to look at it:  a double-dereference only works if it points to an array of pointers somewhere.  However, C/C++ does not do this for you; you would need to allocate and fill one yourself.

The `int (*)[2]` type is what allows you to access the array-of-arrays as `data[i][j]`.  If you want to access the array that way, you need to propagate that type everywhere it is used.